# Using static methods/structures to pass data between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

If I want to pass data between activities in the same application, a) I can use an `Intent` or b) use a database (passing the id in the `Intent` instead of the full data.
But I could also use c) a class with static data structures that both activities can access in a store/fetch fashion.
What are the cons of using (c) if I don't care about persistence of the data on app restart?

Comment: The c option is the example of Repository pattern, and the repository is singleton.

Comment: @ManuelMato: I thought the repository pattern means access to a DB (or remote server DB)

Comment: I use the repository to create a flow data between more datasource and use too a cache datasource, but if you haven´t more datasource, maybe you could do all in the repository class

Comment: @ManuelMato: Your suggestion helps on how to properly design the code. But the question is about potential issues we face by storing the data in static structures during the activities lifecycle

Comment: ah ooki, I had not understood the statement, sorry xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big cons is that the Android OS can kill your process at any time. When the process will be re-created, Android will re-create all of your activities restoring their state.

Since Android doesn't know about how your static data should be handled, you will lose it and Activity B will be in an inconsistent state.

I'll make an example to be clearer:

1. Activity A is launched
2. A button on Activity A is clicked
3. Static data structures are being populated before launching Activity B
4. Activity B is launched and can access the static data
5. Android OS kills automatically your process
6. Activity A and Activity B are restored
7. The static data structures are not populated since they would have been populated when the button on Activity A is clicked
8. Activity B is in an inconsistent state