# Moving data back and forth between two open activities

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities- act1 and act2. I want to transfer a String from act1 to act2 when the user presses a button and after some computation I want to transfer a `LatLng` from act2 to act1, while keeping both activities open (or at least be able to restore every change in act2 from the app start).

---

**Things I tried:**

- I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826483/go-back-to-specific-activity-from-stack/23826550) that if I add some flags to the intent I won't start new activities when using `startActivity()`. It works well getting from act1 to act2 but after starting act1 from act2 it stops act2, so in the next act2 opening it will make a new act2 copy.
- I looked at the not-deprecated version of `startActivityForResult`, but since I need both of the activities open it's not what I want. I also want both of them to receive and return data.
- From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60735595/using-static-methods-structures-to-pass-data-between-activities), using static data structure in one activity may not be good practice.
- I tried using extras and `onNewIntent` but couldn't make it work (since I can't keep both activities running).

---

**Background** (if relevant):

I have an app with two activities- main, which stores a `ListView`, and a map activity.

The map must have a marker placed in each saved address.

The list has two button types:

1. "Add a new place...", that open the map activity, and adds a new marker where the user wants.
2. -some address-, that open the map in the location corresponding to this address.

I need a way to pass the desired address to the map so it'll show this location, and I also need to pass the new saved address back to the main activity after creating a location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *repository pattern* to store the data in a way accessible by all code in your app.

## What is a *repository*?

A repository is a simple class that holds some data and provides access to it. Something like:

```
class Repository {
    
    private String theString = "";

    public void setTheString(String newValue) {
        theString = newValue;
    }

    public String getTheString( {
        return theString;
    }
}
```

*It's a good idea to give a more descriptive name to the repository. So if this is a repository that stores location data, you could name it `LocationRepository`.*

## Where should it be created?

A good place to keep the reference to it is the `Application` class. If you don't have one, you can define it like this:

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
    
    private Repository repository = new Repository();

    public Repository getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }    
}
```

- It needs to extend the `Application` class provided by the android framework
- You can also override the `onCreate()` method for more complex initialization, if necessary in your case

### Define the application class in the manifest

In order for the android framework to know about your custom `Application` class you need to define it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
```

## Access the repository in your activities

Now in each activity you can cast the application context into your application class:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Repository repository = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getRepository();
        System.out.println(repository.getTheString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a few questions:
1. I don't know Kotlin, can you please explain the first (new) line of onCreate?
2.  Why do I need the repository to extend Application, if it onlt stores some data?
3. How can I access the *same* repository object from both activities?

Comment: I will answer the last question first: Using the code above (`val repository = (applicationContext as MyApplication).repository`) you are able to access the same repository object from both activities. You need to extend `Application` in order to keep the repository inside it. I can provide the sample in Java if it would help you more.

Comment: I would appreciate a sample in Java, meanwhile I just use static lists

Comment: I changed the sample to Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a cleaner approach, where you care about architecture design:

- Create a ViewModel per each activity
- Create a Singleton, which the ViewModels access, and use it to share the data.

The Singleton could be something like:

```
object AddressManager{
    
    fun saveAddress(address: Address) {
        
    }
    
    fun getAddress(): Address{
        
    }
}
```

And of course, I would advise you to use Dagger and Hilt for the injection and not to use "object", but this is again more and more design ideas.

Comment: Is there a problem with onNewIntent? I thought this is he way to go, just need to prevent the second activity from getting stopped.
Anyway I'll also look into singeltons. btw I'm using java.

Comment: You are saying that onNewIntent is not working. Not me. Second of all - you should make a distinction between stopped and killed. They are totally different. I am not sure what exactly is preventing you to use onNewIntent.       About creating Singletons in Java - there is a lot of info about it. But the modern way of doing things is ViewModel, LiveData, etc. If you make a complex interaction between screens, using mostly UI API - this is not ok.

Comment: I'll clarify: When I start the app, act1 is created. I always start activities with the flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. Then I start act2 and it's also creating. Now I start act1 from act2, and it enters onNewIntent of act1  (so far so good). The problem is that act2 stops at this point, and when I start it again from act1 (it should resume to it), it creates act2 again

Comment: Using Dagger/Hilt would be overkill for this (simple) case. Also no need for it to be a singleton. It can be a regular object which is created inside your own `Application` class.